mercadopago pago con tarjeta
tengo una situacion molesta con mercadopago, lo que sucede es que quiero que el usuario pague sin iniciar sesion osea que con el init link pague desde cualquier lugar cualquier persona que tenga las tarjetas de prueba de mercadopago pero no me deja hacerlo solo me deja hacerlo si tengo el usuario de prueba en sesion se puede o estoy perdiendo el tiempo? por cierto este es mi body:
  binary_mode: true,

  payer: {
    name: 'Josue',
    surname: 'Vasquez',
    email: '1vN9S@example.com'
  },
  back_urls: {
    success: 'http://localhost:3000/success',
    failure: 'http://localhost:3000/failure'
  },
  auto_return: 'approved',
  payment_methods: {
    excluded_payment_methods: [
      {
        id: 'codensa'
      }
    ],
    excluded_payment_types: [],
    installments: 1
  }

